# Get client computer name in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The method below is used to get the client machine name in MVC 4. I've noticed that for some clients it returns an empty string, any idea why this could happen?

Is there another,more reliable way to get the clients machine name?

```
private string GetWorkstation()
    {
        string ip = Request.UserHostName;
        IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);
        List<string> compName = GetIPHost.HostName.ToString().Split('.').ToList();
        return compName.First().ToUpper();
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the question?@Jonesy

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585717/asp-net-request-userhostname-not-containing-hostname

Comment: Do you know when it fails to get the hostname, can you perhaps log `ip` to get a hint?

Comment: @Deepu: The OP is already using `Dns.GetHostEntry`, how does that question help?

Comment: @Patrick IP addresses may change if they are given by DHCP so are not a valid way to determine the client.

Comment: @Denis Are these internal addresses (i.e. an Intranet application) or external Internet addresses?

Comment: @DavidG: That's why I was asking what `Request.UserHostName` is when the Dns lookup fails to give the expected value. The question at the moment is difficult to answer, since we have no way of knowing what the intermediary values are.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()`